# How do I point to the proper file path for an image in Python using VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

Working through a course to learn Python and current project has us loading a .gif as background. Here is my current code, which is same as what instructor is using in video.

```
import turtle 


screen = turtle.Screen() 
screen.title("THE STATES GAME")
#This path copy and pasted using rightclick in VS Explorer
#Started with image = "blank_states_img.gif" "
image = "D:\learnToProgram\Day 25\day25_state_start\blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

answer = screen.textinput(title="Guess the States", prompt="Give me a state:")

screen.exitonclick()
```

VS Code Gives:

> PS D:\learnToProgram\Day 25>  d:; cd 'd:\learnToProgram\Day 25'; & 'C:\Users\lanie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\lanie.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '57939' '--' 'd:\learnToProgram\Day 25\day25_state_start\main.py'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\learnToProgram\Day 25\day25_state_start\main.py", line 9, in <module>
> screen.addshape(image)
> File "C:\Users\lanie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 1134, in register_shape
> shape = Shape("image", self.*image(name))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\lanie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 479, in image
> return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\lanie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_init*.py", line 4130, in **init**
> Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
> File "C:\Users\lanie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*.py", line 4075, in **init**
> self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "blank_states_img.gif": no such file or directory
> PS D:\learnToProgram\Day 25>

I have tried to change the file path to various degrees. From what I see I assume this is a path issue because the file is on my D:\ and when I run the code it looks into C:\

I am looking for info I can read to understand how the whole "path" thing works. Currently, I conceptually understand but it is still magic

I am also looking for what to do in VS Code or in Python to make this work without moving the file. I assume this is an inefficient way to do business, but I want to learn more about why this is: a VS Code thing, a general coding thing, a path thing, a something else thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use normal forward slashes in your path, NOT the backslashes. This is what breaks your path, since the backslash identifies an escape sequence.